# as.Date doesn't retain the time in R

Tags: r

I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
as.Date('2001-10-26 10:00:00', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

It returns

```
"2001-10-26"
```

but I expected it to be

`"2001-10-26 10:00:00"`.

I don't need anything complicated; just to convert a string to a date with a timestamp. Not sure why the format argument isn't working.

Thanks.

Comment: try `strptime('2001-10-26 10:00:00', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: I don't want a time zone or anything, can I avoid having to use `strptime`?

Comment: use `as.POSIXct` instead?

Comment: The chron package supports datetimes with no timezone.

Comment: The standard if you don't want a timezone to affect your results is to use "UTC" as it doesn't have daylight saving etc.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, but I'm really wondering, what is wrong with the format argument as I had it written? There is a reason that `%H:%M:%S` exists, no?

Comment: `chron::chron('2001-10-26', '10:00:00', format = c("Y-m-d", "h:m:s"))` as @G.Grothendieck proposed.  Result is `[1] (01-10-26 10:00:00)`

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck - `Date`s don't have times. `?DateTimeClasses` like those via `as.POSIXct` or `as.POSIXlt` have a date+time+timezone. Those are essentially your two options unless you use an extension package as suggested by others here.

Comment: To use chron: `library(chron); as.chron('2001-10-26 10:00:00')`

Comment: Or you could do it the hard way, either one ;)

Comment: @thelatemail 'Dates don't have times'. That seems counterintuitive. Hours, min, seconds are the units that combine to create months, days years. That's like someone deciding, 'There is no cents in American currency, only dollars, which are made of 100 cents.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R has several ways (expressed in classes) to deal with time and dates. In your fist code you are using the `as.Date` function that converts its arguments to `Date` class. The string you are providing to that function contains also other elements that do not belong to `Date` class and as a result it prints only elements that the function is allowed to handle. As you can read in the documentation:

> ... (dates)... They are always printed following the rules of the current Gregorian
>   calendar, even though that calendar was not in use long ago (it was
>   adopted in 1752 in Great Britain and its colonies).

the informations are essentially lost.
See here:

```
a <- as.Date('2001-10-26 10:00:00', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
format(a, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
[1] "2001-10-26 00:00:00"
```

If you want to keep informations about the time and not only the dates you have to use a format that is able to store that informations. The classes are `POSIXct` and `POSIXlt` where the first one is just a huge integer that counts the seconds since 1970-01-01 and the second one is just a list where each element stores seconds, days, months etc.

The functions (in base R) you have to use are: `strptime` (as pointed out in comments by @nongkrong), or `as.POSIXlt` or `as.POSIXct`.
There are other functions in other packages (like `chron` and `lubridate`) but putting aside special classes developed by single packages (like `period` in `lubridate`) the key classes are the ones I've just illustrated here.

Comment: So from reading your answer, what is the point of using `as.Date` in base R? It seems like a red herring.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck your question can be answered with an inclusion of personal tastes I guess. Here I say that the class of objects might depends on what your data are and what your goals are. They just serve different purposes I think.